# Converter TIME() do PHP em DateTime com JavaScript

Tags: php, javascript

Como converter um `time()` gerado com um PHP para um DateTime estilo este:

```
2015-07-14 21:42:44
```

Comment: Algumas das respostas lhe ajudou? Se não, comente na resposta informando o problema que enfrenta com ela, se sim então marque a resposta que lhe ajudou como correta, clicando em ✓

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alternativa semelhante ao do [@FelipeDouradinho](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/72579/3635), mas neste caso obtemos dias e meses, dias, horas, minutos e segundos abaixo de `10` terão um `0` na frente:

```
var date = new Date(<?php echo $_SERVER['REQUEST_TIME']; ?> * 1000);
var ano  = date.getFullYear();
var mes  = date.getMonth() + 1;
var dia  = date.getDate();
var hora = date.getHours();
var min  = date.getMinutes();
var seg  = date.getSeconds();

mes  = mes  > 9 ? mes  : ("0" + "" + mes);
dia  = dia  > 9 ? dia  : ("0" + "" + dia);
hora = hora > 9 ? hora : ("0" + "" + hora);
min  = min  > 9 ? min  : ("0" + "" + min);
seg  = seg  > 9 ? seg  : ("0" + "" + seg);

data = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + " " + hora + ":" + min + ":" + seg;

console.log(data);
```

```js
function formatDate(time) {
    var date = new Date(time * 1000);
    var ano  = date.getFullYear();
    var mes  = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var dia  = date.getDate();
    var hora = date.getHours();
    var min  = date.getMinutes();
    var seg  = date.getSeconds();

    mes  = mes  > 9 ? mes  : ("0" + "" + mes);
    dia  = dia  > 9 ? dia  : ("0" + "" + dia);
    hora = hora > 9 ? hora : ("0" + "" + hora);
    min  = min  > 9 ? min  : ("0" + "" + min);
    seg  = seg  > 9 ? seg  : ("0" + "" + seg);

    data = ano + "-" + mes + "-" + dia + " " + hora + ":" + min + ":" + seg;

   return data;
}

var btn     = document.getElementById("myButton");
var target  = document.getElementById("target");

btn.onclick = function() {
    target.innerHTML = formatDate(1435881123);    
};
```

```html
<div id="target"></div>
<button id="myButton">Testar</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

Use o [Date](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/Core_JavaScript_1.5_Reference/Global_Objects/Date) para fazer isso:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var data = new Date(<?php echo time(); ?> * 1000);
    data = ""+data.getFullYear()+"-"+(data.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+data.getDate()+" "+data.getHours()+":"+data.getMinutes()+":"+data.getSeconds()+"";

    alert(data);
</script>
```

Exemplo:

```js
// Formato 2015-07-14 21:42:44

var data = new Date(1435881123 * 1000);
data = ""+data.getFullYear()+"-"+(data.getMonth() + 1)+"-"+data.getDate()+" "+data.getHours()+":"+data.getMinutes()+":"+data.getSeconds()+"";

alert(data);
```

[**jsfiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/felipe_douradinho/kkkhdw2k/3/)

Comment: Oi Felipe. Olhando suas respostas (e você tem respondido bastante, parabéns!), percebi que muitas (todas?) começam com "**nome do autor da pergunta,**". Isso não é proibido, mas a [recomendação oficial é não usar cumprimentos](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/behavior). Eu também [já expus meus argumentos contra esse tipo de conteúdo](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/851). Também acredito que [o site deve privilegiar a comunicação com grupos de pessoas, e não indivíduos](http://meta.pt.stackoverflow.com/a/4007). Você pode discordar, mas peço que considere meus argumentos :) Obrigado

Comment: Opa...joia, pode deixar... E obrigado pelo elogio :)